# Dynamically generate form inputs based on two models of data in ember

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, auto-generate

I'm currently trying to generate forms dynamically in Ember with Ember-data. The form fields required depend on the content type of the publishable being loaded when the route `publishables/:publishable_id/edit` is accessed.

**Data sources:**

**models/settings.js**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Settings = DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr(),
  fields: DS.attr()
});

Settings.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: 'Gallery',
      fields: [
        {type: 'text', name: 'name', description: 'desc1'},
        {type: 'text', name: 'email', description: 'desc2'},
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      type: 'article',
      fields: [
        {type: 'text', name: 'name', description: 'desc1'},
        {type: 'textarea', name: 'notes', description: 'desc2'}
      ]
    }
  ]
});

export default Settings;
```

**models/publishable.js**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Publishable = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),

  authors: DS.hasMany('author', { async: true }),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true }),

  published: DS.attr(),
  publish_from: DS.attr(),
  slug: DS.attr(),

  name: DS.attr(),
  fields: DS.attr(),

  contentType: DS.attr()
});

Publishable.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'How do I feed hamsters?',
      description: 'description 1',
      slug: 'derp',
      author: [
        {name: 'Tom Dale'}
      ],
      publish_from: "2014-07-14T23:11:48Z",
      question: 'Tomster cant eat using knife and a fork because his hands are too small. We are looking for a way to feed him. Any ideas?',
      contentType: {
        name: 'Gallery'
      },
      name: 'somedumname',
      email: 'herp@derp.com',
      passwordConfirmation: 'lolololololol',
      fields: { name: 'somedumname', email: 'herp@derp.com', passwordConfirmation: 'lolololololol' }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Are humans insane?',
      description: 'description 2',
      author: 'Tomster the Hamster',
      date: '2013-02-02T12:00:00',
      question: 'I mean are totaly nuts? Is there any hope left for them? Should we hamsters try to save them?',
      contentType: {
        name: 'article'
      },
      fields: {name: 'hehehe', notes: 'lolololol'}
    }
  ]
});

export default Publishable;
```

For example, when `pubishables/1/edit` is accessed, a form will generate based on `App.Publishable.FIXTURE[:publishable_id].contentType.name === App.Settings.FIXTURE[:publishable_id].type`. Or, since the current publishable's content type is 'Gallery', `fields` data from `Settings` based on `Settings.type === 'Gallery'` will be grabbed.

In the case of `/1/`, two inputs need to be generated:

```
{type: 'text', name: 'name', description: 'desc1'},
{type: 'text', name: 'email', description: 'desc2'}
```

Where the input type is `type`, the description is `description`, and the value is **App.Publishable.FIXTURE[:publishable_id].field[App.Settings.FIXTURE[:publishable_id].fields[i].name]**. Or in the case for the first input, it will need to be populated with `App.Publishable.FIXTURE[:publishable_id].field.name`. (or in the case of the second input `App.Publishable.FIXTURE[:publishable_id].field.email`).

This is the part that I've been struggling with. How to relate the fields getting auto generated based on the `Settings` model, and the corresponding value from the `Publishable` model.

Currently I am doing a bit of a hack via the `PublishableController`:

**controllers/publishables.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['settings'],
  settings: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.settings.model'),
  formFields: function() {

    var modelFields = this.get('model.fields');
    var settingsFields = this.get('settings.content')[0].get('fields'); // a bit of a hack, unsure how to do this better.

    var inputArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < settingsFields.length; i++) {

      var tmpObj = {};

      for (var property in settingsFields[i]) {
        if (settingsFields[i].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          tmpObj[property] = settingsFields[i][property]
          if(modelFields[settingsFields[i][property]]) {
            tmpObj['content'] = modelFields[settingsFields[i][property]];
          }
        }
      }

      inputArray.push(tmpObj);

    }

    return inputArray;

  }.property(this)
});
```

Where I:

1. Create an array
2. Create a temp object
3. Iterate over the settings model and add all its properties to the temp object
4. Find the relationship between `Settings.fields.name` and `Publishable.fields[Settings.fields.name]` and key it as 'content' in the temp object
5. Push the temp object to the array
6. Return the new array so I can loop over it in the view as `{{#each formFields}}`

This works wonders for generating the form with the appropriate value from the `Publishable` model. The only problem with this is I lose context of the `Publishable` model. I'm at a loss as how to proceed editing the input values and saving them back to the model.

Here is the template:

**templates/publishable/edit.hbs**:

```
<form>
{{#each formFields}}
  {{input name=name type=type value=content}}
  {{description}}
{{/each}}
</form>
```

I was thinking of doing a .set() the different input values based on `name`, but that seems very clunky.

Is there a better way to associate the auto generated inputs based on `Settings` and values from the `Publishable` model? Or is there some way I can observe the inputs so when I hit submit on the form that I can update the model?

Comment: Have you Checked out ember easy-form? It's pretty sweet for this sort of thing my help.